# PyBrain Neural Net does not converge for a simple f(x) = x+1 function

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I am using the following PyBrain Neural Network code to add a 1 to a given input. The code somehow never converges.

I tried various learning rates and different number of hidden layers, neurons etc. without any luck.

Any help?

```
import numpy, math
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.structure import SigmoidLayer, LinearLayer
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork

net = buildNetwork(1,
                   100, # number of hidden units
                   1,
                   bias = True,
                   hiddenclass = SigmoidLayer,
                   outclass = LinearLayer
                   )

xvalues = numpy.arange(100)
yvalues = (xvalues) + 1

ds = SupervisedDataSet(1, 1)
for x, y in zip(xvalues, yvalues):
    ds.addSample((x,), (y,))

print(ds['input'])
print(ds['target'])

trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds, verbose=True)
trainer.trainUntilConvergence()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y=xvalues
y_lin = [ net.activate([x]) for x in xvalues ]
ax.plot(y, y_lin, 'bo', lw=4)
ax.plot(y, yvalues, 'r^', lw=2)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

See the difference between expected and predicted values.

Weird thing is if I give 10 training values instead of 100 the net seems converge.

Thanks.

Comment: change learningrate :)

Comment: Thank you. I changed the learning rate to the following and now it is converging.   learningrate=0.001, momentum=0.05

Comment: @CyberStudent you should add that as an answer :)